# When you prestige, do you always start at level 1?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

A friend of mine didn't realise you had to do something in *Barracks* in order to Prestige in Black Op 2 and has been playing the recent double XP weekend at Level 55.

If he prestiges now, will the game:

- Take his XP into account and start him at, say, Prestige 1, Level 25?
- Ignore his XP and start him at Prestige 1, Level 1?

Comment: Presige always start with level 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately all of that experience is lost.  He'll start a Prestige 1, Level 1 as soon as he chooses the option in the barracks.  I think the explanation is pretty simple, as people would just camp at max level of their current prestige, then enter again once they had enough to be fairly high leveled into the next prestige level.

Comment: @turbo : please note that in BO2, there are no "pro" perks, and you don't loose your challenges ! ;)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, gave up on the COD after MW3. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Prestiging always starts you back at level 1, It takes away your classes and all. Just remember when you bought your game, it is the exact same thing.

Comment: Not exactly the same thing, you don't lose challenges, and when you unlock a gun after prestiging, it goes back to the exact state it was before prestiging (level and camos/accessories unlocked). Plus you get a permanent unlock token and a prestige coin.